# Incorrect menu anchor position - fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I have website with few section inside another divs. Maybe this is reason but I'm not sure.
When I click on menu item page scroll to wrong position and correctly work only in section directly under body. Is here any solution for work it with my page layout?

https://dimmuboy.tk/pikaro.sk

Comment: Why do you need fullpage.js for this? Your sections aren't full pages/viewport, and this could be achieved with simple JS and scrollto using anchors.

Comment: Can you please display the code you think isn't working?

Comment: Are you mentioning the blue part overlapping the red part?

Comment: It's about all menu sections except about and contact but @dom_ahdigital you have good note, I only use layout from my other page but I not need fullpage.js for this